# How to created a sentiment analysis metric from individual pieces of data

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I have an array of news articles I get daily. I run a sentiment model and get a value between -1.5 and 1.5. My question is how do I combine each say days worth of individual values between -1.5 and 1.5 into a single value. Do I just do it based on averages? Do I weight it by amount of text analyzed?